# Get values from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, ecmascript-6

I am looping through my array to get the corresponding field value:

```
var someFun = function (nm) {
    var names = [{name: 'joe', age: 'nine'}, {name: 'tom', age: 'ten'}];

    for (var i=0; i < names.length; i++) {
        if (names[i].name === nm) return names[i].age;
    }
};

var username = 'tom';
var printme = someFun(username);
console.log('hey: ', printme)
```

How can I do the same using `Object.keys()`, or map, or forEach? Much cleaner and ES6 compliant.

Comment: `names` is an array. You would *not* use `Object.keys`!

Comment: `return {joe: 'nine', tom: 'ten'}[nm];` would do the job :-)

Comment: `for(var key in names[i]){ console.log("key: " + key + ", value: " + names[i][key]); }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `find`

```
([{name: 'joe', age: 'nine'}, {name: 'tom', age: 'ten'}].find( (s)=> s.name=="tom" )||{}).age //10

([{name: 'joe', age: 'nine'}, {name: 'tom', age: 'ten'}].find( (s)=> s.name=="tom2" )||{}).age //undefined
```

**Demo**

```js
var names = [{
  name: 'joe',
  age: 'nine'
}, {
  name: 'tom',
  age: 'ten'
}];

function getAge(names, name) {
  return (names.find((s) => s.name == name) || {}).age;
}

console.log(getAge(names, "tom"))
console.log(getAge(names, "tom2"))
```

Comment: This throws an exception when it doesn't find Tom.

Comment: @Bergi fixed it

Answer (score 1):

You can use *array.prototype.find*:

```js
var names = [{name: 'joe', age: 'nine'}, {name: 'tom', age: 'ten'}];
var someFun = (nm) => {        
    var found = names.find(el => el.name === nm);
    return found && found.age || null; 
}
console.log(someFun('tom'));
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

> The find() method returns the value of the **first** element in the array
>   that satisfies the provided testing function.

If there are multiples objects with the same name?

With [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var names = [{
    name: 'joe',
    age: 9
  },
  {
    name: 'tom',
    age: 10
  },
  {
    name: 'frank',
    age: 9
  },
  {
    name: 'joe',
    age: 15
  }
];

function getData(arr, search) {
  // Filter array of objects by a search pair
  return arr.filter(o => o[search[0]] === search[1]);
}

function listBy(arr, k) {
  // Output values from an array of objects by a key as a comma separated string 
  return arr.map(o => o[k]).join(",");
}

console.log(getData(names, ["name", "joe"]));
console.log(listBy(getData(names, ["name", "tom"]), "age"));
console.log(listBy(getData(names, ["age", 9]), "name"));
```

Answer (score 0):

IE doesn't support `find`, check the [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). Maybe you don't need to support IE, but it's still a gets [3.74% of global usage](http://gs.statcounter.com/) as of Oct 2017. However, it does support [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yunoxaxudi/edit?js,console)

```
var users = [
  { name: "Bill", age: 'nine' },
  { name: 'Tedd', age: 'ten' }
];

function getAgeFromUsers(name) {
  const arr = users.filter(u => u.name === name);
  return !!arr.length ? arr[0].age : "That user ain't here";
}

console.log(getAgeFromUsers('Tedd'));
console.log(getAgeFromUsers("Lion 'O"));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var someFun = nm => {
    const names = [{name: 'joe', age: 'nine'}, {name: 'tom', age: 'ten'}];
    const foundName = names.find(name => name.name === nm)

    return foundName ? foundName.age : null
};
```

This replicates what you have above. Although i would personally return the object then age the age from that instead of just returning the age.

Comment: This throws an exception when it doesn't find Tom.

Comment: Good spot, amended.

Comment: Thanks. The variable should be named `boy`, not `foundName` though

Comment: Assuming all the names will be boy names, that would work. I think playing off the original variables name makes a bit more sense though.